# Make subplots of the histogram in pandas dataframe using matpolot library?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

**I have the following data separate by tab:**

```
CHROM   ms02g:PI    num_Vars_by_PI  range_of_PI total_haplotypes    total_Vars
1   1,2 60,6    2820,81 2   66
2   9,8,10,7,11 94,78,10,69,25  89910,1102167,600,1621365,636   5   276
3   5,3,4,6 6,12,14,17  908,394,759,115656  4   49
4   17,18,22,16,19,21,20    22,11,3,16,7,12,6   1463,171,149,256,157,388,195    7   77
5   13,15,12,14 56,25,96,107    2600821,858,5666,1792   4   284
7   24,26,29,25,27,23,30,28,31  12,31,19,6,12,23,9,37,25    968,3353,489,116,523,1933,823,2655,331  9   174
8   33,32   53,35   1603,2991338    2   88
```

**I am using this code to build a histogram plots with subplots for each `CHROM`:**

```
with open(outputdir + '/' + 'hap_size_byVar_'+ soi +'_'+ prefix+'.png', 'wb') as fig_initial:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(hap_stats), sharex=True)
    for i, data in hap_stats.iterrows():

        # first convert data to list of integers
        data_i = [int(x) for x in data['num_Vars_by_PI'].split(',')]
        ax[i].hist(data_i, label=str(data['CHROM']), alpha=0.5)
        ax[i].legend()

    plt.xlabel('size of the haplotype (number of variants)')
    plt.ylabel('frequency of the haplotypes')
    plt.suptitle('histogram of size of the haplotype (number of variants) \n'
                 'for each chromosome')
    plt.savefig(fig_initial)
```

**Everything is fine except two problems:**

1. The **Y-label `frequency of the haplotypes`** is not adjusted properly in this output plot.

[image]

2. When the data contain only one row (see data below) the subplot are not possible and I get **`TypeError`**, even though it should be able to make the subgroup with only one index.

**Dataframe with only one line of data:**

```
 CHROM  ms02g:PI    num_Vars_by_PI  range_of_PI total_haplotypes    total_Vars
 2  9,8,10,7,11 94,78,10,69,25  89910,1102167,600,1621365,636   5   276
```

**`TypeError :`**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phase-Extender.py", line 1806, in <module>
    main()
  File "phase-Extender.py", line 502, in main
    compute_haplotype_stats(initial_haplotype, soi, prefix='initial')
  File "phase-Extender.py", line 1719, in compute_haplotype_stats
    ax[i].hist(data_i, label=str(data['CHROM']), alpha=0.5)
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

**How can I fix these two issues ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem comes from the fact that you are using `plt.ylabel()` at the end of your loop. pyplot functions act on the current active axes object, which, in this case, is the last one created by `subplots()`. If you want your label to be centered over your subplots, the easiest might be to create a text object centered vertically in the figure.

```
# replace plt.ylabel('frequency of the haplotypes') with:
fig.text(.02, .5, 'frequency of the haplotypes', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')
```

you can play around with the x-position (0.02) until you find a position you're happy with. The coordinates are in figure coordinates, (0,0) is bottom left (1,1) is top right. Using 0.5 as y position ensures the label is centered in the figure.

The second problem is due to the fact that, when `numrows=1` `plt.subplots()` returns directly the axes object, instead of a list of axes. There are two options to circumvent this problem

1 - test whether you have only one line, and then replace `ax` with a list:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(hap_stats), sharex=True)
if len(hap_stats)==1:
    ax = [ax]
(...)
```

2 - use the option `squeeze=False` in your call to `plt.subplots()`. [As explained in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots), using this option will force `subplots()`to always return a **2D** array. Therefore you'll have to modify a bit how you are indexing your axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(hap_stats), sharex=True, squeeze=False)
    for i, data in hap_stats.iterrows():
        (...)
        ax[i,0].hist(data_i, label=str(data['CHROM']), alpha=0.5)
        (...)
```